# Does Flutter support ED25519 Signatures?

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl

Is ED25519 supported with Flutter? I'm using self signed certificates with ED25519 and I'm receiving the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE(tls_record.cc:594)
    HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO(handshake.cc:603))
```

and in my Go server

```
2022/01/14 12:18:52 http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:53834: EOF
2022/01/14 12:18:52 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:53833: tls: peer doesn't support any of the certificate's signature algorithms
```

To me this indicates that Flutter / Dart does not support ED25519 yet. Is there any way around this, perhaps with HttpOverrides?

Comment: Can you attach the output of running the command: `openssl s_client -connect ipOrDomainToYourServer:443`. It should provide details about what your go-server are providing of certificate information.

Comment: I'm making the certificate, so I'm aware of its configuration, but here is the output:


No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signature type: Ed25519
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 820 bytes and written 361 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Server public key is 256 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---

Comment: Could you add this to your question? The formatting is really bad in comments for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does not appear to support ED25519 by default. By swapping to ECDSA all is resolved. Not an ideal solution as it feels like making a minor security compromise, hopefully Flutter will add this functionality in the near future.

Comment: "hopefully Flutter will add this functionality in the near future.". I hope you have created an issue on the Flutter (or more likely Dart) issue tracker to ensure this is fixed. :)

Comment: Yup I've created a ticket.